# How can I get the max value from specific key in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have this dictionary and I want to get the max value of the ratio key only

I did this:

```
company_dict = {0: {'link': 'www.facebook.com', 'ratio': 0.91, 'size': 3},
                1: {'link': 'www.google.com', 'ratio': 0.92, 'size': 4}}
max_value = 0
for key, value in company_dict.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        if k == 'ratio':
            if v > max_value:
                max_value = v

print(max_value)
```

> Output:
> 0.92

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also gives you the entire dictionary in addition to the max ratio:

```
best_company = max(company_dict.values(), key=lambda d: d["ratio"])
best_ratio = best_company["ratio"]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was searching for Thank you very much ❤

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

```
max(item['ratio'] for item in company_dict.values())
```

**A bit more info:**

You should not iterate through all items to get one of them, like this:

```
for k, v in value.items():
    if k == 'ratio':
```

You can achieve the same with:

```
v = value['ratio']
```

Also, you don't need to implement your own logic to find the maximum, because there is the built-in function `max`.

So, what I did is, I took only the values of all items in `company_dict`:

```
company_dict.values()
```

Then, I took only the `'ratio'` from each of them:

```
item['ratio'] for item in ...
```

And then I just called `max` for all of those ratio values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` keyword argument of the `max` function in combination with a lambda.

```
company_dict = {0: {'link': 'www.facebook.com', 'ratio': 0.91, 'size': 3},
            1: {'link': 'www.google.com', 'ratio': 0.92, 'size': 4}}
max_key = max(company_dict, key=lambda x: company_dict[x]['ratio'])
print(company_dict[max_key]['ratio'])
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was searching for Thank you very much ❤